# Play video network required secure header

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-video-player

video_player: ^2.1.4
My server request Authorization on header and i has insert it into header:

```
VideoPlayerController controller = VideoPlayerController.network({URL}, httpHeaders: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}' });
```

But doesn't seem to work!
I give error:

```
PlatformException(MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED, No further diagnostic information can be determined or provided., The video has been found to be unsuitable (missing or in a format not supported by your browser)., null)
```

#additional:
This error when play video on flutter web application

Who can help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Could you inspect the network with the dev tools to make sure that you are downloading the video properly?

Comment: Tks @Gpack.
When i call this url with dio (header bearer) that work fine.And I sure my token is live

Comment: If your going to use `${token}` then you need to use template literals (backticks) not single quotes

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found issue.
Because this package write on VideoElement - html library, but VideoElement not support header authentication.
Looks like this will come to a standstill if flutter dev doesn't support it!

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/VideoElement-class.html
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/video_player/video_player_web/lib/video_player_web.dart

And I had create issue on github
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83602